# Detour - Expression Engine Addon not working

Tags: detour-pro

EE 7.3.14
Detour 3.0.2

Redirects are not working at all
Redirects are properly formatted
tried both EE and PHP url detection methods

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to your server configuration. Are you properly routing all traffic through the ExpressionEngine index.php file?

You may need to update your [.htaccess file](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/best-practices.html#1-create-an-htaccess-file) or your [nginx config](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/expressionengine/) depending on your server type.